# Angular get in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular. The following code works:

```
.controller('abc', function ($scope, $http)
{
$http.get("/Handlers/Authentication.ashx")
  .success(function (data)
  {
    alert(data);
  })
```

This function however does not:

```
.controller('abc', function ($scope, $http)
{
$scope.run = function ($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('/Handlers/Authentication.ashx');
    //  .success(function (data)
    //{
    //  alert(data);
    //});
};
}
```

I know that I should use a service here. But for learning purposes I would like to know why it does not work to call this function inside:

```
<body ng-app="MainModule">
<div ng-controller="abc">
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="run();">{{xx}}</button>
```

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding controller injected `$http` service here :

```
$scope.run = function ($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('/Handlers/Authentication.ashx');
    //  .success(function (data)
    //{
    //  alert(data);
    //});
};
```

Just remove all arguments on your scope function and it should work :

```
.controller('abc', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.run = function () {
        $http.get('/Handlers/Authentication.ashx')
            .success(function (data){
                alert(data);
            });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting data, but don't doing with it something.

```
$http.get('/Handlers/Authentication.ashx').then(function(data){
       console.log(data);
}, function(err){
   console.log(err);
 })
```